# jpeg does not contain metadata

Tags: metadata, jpeg, exif, avi

I convert AVI to jpeg. I want to analyze EXIF metadata from jpeg, however, the jpeg file that already converted from AVI does not contain any metadata. Why is the EXIF metadata missing? it is because of the jpeg files originality from AVI?

Comment: It is most probably because the tool you used to convert your avi file to jpeg images didn't include it. What tool did you use? *And who did upvote your barely on topic question?*

Answer (score 0):

EXIF is one of several JPEG file format in use. It is not defined by the JPEG standard. There are a number of reasons why you may not find EXIF metadata in your JPEG stream.

First, it is likely that your AVI did not contain such metadata to begin with so there is no metadata to encode.

Second, your AVI to JPEG encoder may not even create EXIF format JPEG streams.